# Syntax Highlighting for AppleScript

Tags: feature-request, formatting

It would be nice to have proper syntax highlighting for AppleScript used in code blocks, especially since AppleScript is the primary language posted on this site.  Currently the auto-detection usually guesses either SQL or VB.net.

This is already implemented by [highlight.js](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/master/src/languages/applescript.js); it just needs to be deployed by Stack Exchange.  The tag info page shows there is currently no syntax highlighting for AppleScript.
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/applescript/info

As an example, here is code highlighted from this [popular answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/36947/49400).
[image]

Here is how it looks in highlight.js version 9.18
[image]